# Docmd.Openform Opening a blank Form?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a small piece of code that is embedded into a button on a continuous form.  It will open a form to give additional details not on the search result.

My problem is this, It seems that when all the details are present the form opens correctly, if any fields are missing (say a pay date or voucher number), the form opens blank?

Here is the code for the search query, and the code to the button to open the form:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim strsearch As String
Dim strText As String
strText = Me.txtSearch.Value
strsearch = "Select * from tblInvoiceLog where Vendor_Number like ""*" & strText & "*"" or Vendor_Name like ""*" & strText & "*"" or Invoice_1 like ""*" & strText & "*"" or Invoice_2 like ""*" & strText & "*"" or Invoice_3 like ""*" & strText & "*"" or Invoice_4 like ""*" & strText & "*"" or Invoice_5 like ""*" & strText & "*"" or Check_Request_Total like ""*" & strText & "*"" or Voucher_Number like ""*" & strText & "*"" or Notes like ""*" & strText & "*"" or TransAction_Id like ""*" & strText & "*"" ORDER BY [Pay_Date] DESC"
Me.RecordSource = strsearch
End Sub

Private Sub Command53_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm: Check Request Info (Redesign)", , , "TransAction_Id = " & TransAction_ID
End Sub
```

I thought I accounted for all the variables in this equation?
Can any one offer a suggestion?

Comment: So you are looking for one given string in many different fields, correct? Why are you setting 'Me.Recordsource'? That is your current form.

Comment: The txtsearch is on the form, do I not have to declare the "me" if the field is named?

Comment: No, I mean your line "Me.RecordSource = strsearch" is going to reset the recordsource for the current form that your "Command1" button is located on. Have you tried placing a breakpoint in "Command53_Click" to see what is in "TransAction_ID"? I also would grab the sql for the form you are opening and execute it manually. If no records are returned, start deleting criteria until it works. Then you will find out why it fails.

Comment: Its just that all the criteria need to be present for that search box to be of any value?  And the search part works, how does that effect the docmd action? Where it is only looking at the [TransAction_Id]?

Comment: To confirm: (1) you enter text into txtSearch, then press 'Command1' button? (2) That correctly requeries your form to filter using 'txtSearch'? (3) When you click 'Command53' it opens 'frm...' passing variable 'TransAction_ID'? You said the search part works, so that means the issue lies with: (a) the recordset of the form you are opening, or (b) the value you are passing (I assume you use it as a filter or something???) These were the reasons for suggesting (above) a breakpoint and to run the forms query by itself. Please confirm/correct my understanding.

Comment: Wayne - You were correct! The record source on the 2 forms were different.  Once I pointed them to the same source, everything worked as expected.  Thank you very much for keeping in touch,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your record sources all point to the same table/query when using multiple forms/sub forms.  A novice answer/problem for sure, but it could save a headache Thank you Wayne G. Dunn